# memcpy returns junk data when copying from character buffer

Tags: c

I'm attempting to read 4 bytes from the start of a character buffer, but I'm having an issue. `memcpy` is returning junk.

`buffer` contains the contents of the file. Using breakpoints I see that the file starts with `41 53 45 46` or `ASEF` in ASCII. This is the file signature for an [Adobe Swatch File](https://medium.com/swlh/mastering-adobe-color-file-formats-d29e43fde8eb#:%7E:text=For%20this%20purpose%2C%20Adobe%20offers,the%20most%20commonly%20used%20formats).

But when I copy those 4 bytes from a character buffer, to a 4 byte array `signature`, I get random data.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    errno_t err = NULL;
    FILE *fptr = NULL;
    long fileSize = 0;
    unsigned char* buffer;
    int i, bytesRead;
    
    char signature[4] = { 0 };
    
    err = fopen_s(&fptr, argv[1], "rb");
    if (err || fptr == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not open file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }

    // Get filesize
    fseek(fptr, 0, SEEK_END);
    fileSize = ftell(fptr);
    rewind(fptr);

    // Allocate memory to store file contents
    buffer = malloc(fileSize);
    if (buffer == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Could not allocate %i bytes of memory\n", fileSize);
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Read file contents into buffer
    bytesRead = fread(buffer, 1, fileSize, fptr);
    if (bytesRead == 0) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to read bytes from file: %s\n", argv[1]);
        return 1;
    }
    
    // Read and check signature
    memcpy(signature, &buffer, 4);

    fclose(fptr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Shouldn't `bytesRead == 0` be `bytesRead < 4`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This line is wrong:

```
memcpy(signature, &buffer, 4);
```

You want to copy the data in your buffer, not the value of the buffer pointer itself. That means you want:

```
memcpy(signature, buffer, 4);
```

Comment: Ah yes. Thank you. I get a warning `Reading invalid data from buffer: the readable size is fileSize but 4 bytes may be read`. Links here, but can't figure it out: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/c6385?view=msvc-160&viewFallbackFrom=vs-2019

Comment: That's because you didn't check that fileSize was `>= 4` anywhere.